# ¿Cómo obtener el total de entradas y salidas según el mes y año en una sola consulta sql?

Tags: mysql, group-by

Tengo 3 tablas relacionadas:

1. producto (id_producto, codigo_producto, nombre_producto, descripcion_producto)
2. entradas (id_entrada, producto, cantidad_entrada, fecha_entrada)
3. salidas (id_salida, producto, cantidad_salida, fecha_salida)

Me gustaría obtener el total de entradas y salidas (en un determinado mes y año) en una sola consulta para llenar una tabla html. Por ahora, tengo dos consultas:

```
SELECT producto.codigo_producto,
  SUM(entradas.cantidad_entrada) AS total_entradas,
  entradas.fecha_entrada
  FROM producto JOIN entradas
  ON producto.id_producto = entradas.producto
  WHERE MONTH(entradas.fecha_entrada)
  AND YEAR(fecha_entrada) = '2018'
  GROUP BY producto.codigo_producto
  ORDER BY producto.codigo_producto ASC;

SELECT producto.codigo_producto,
  SUM(salidas.cantidad_salida) AS total_salidas,
  salidas.fecha_salida
  FROM producto JOIN salidas
  ON producto.id_producto = salidas.producto
  WHERE MONTH(salidas.fecha_salida)
  AND YEAR(fecha_salida) = '2018'
  GROUP BY producto.codigo_producto
  ORDER BY producto.codigo_producto ASC;
```

Y necesito algo como esto (filtrado por mes y año):

```
SELECT producto.codigo_producto,
  SUM(entradas.cantidad_entrada) AS total_entradas,
  SUM(salidas.cantidad_salida) AS total_salidas
  FROM producto
  INNER JOIN entradas
  ON producto.id_producto = entradas.producto
  INNER JOIN salidas
  ON producto.id_producto = salidas.producto
  GROUP BY producto.codigo_producto
  ORDER BY producto.codigo_producto ASC;
```

Estos son algunos de los datos que estoy utilizando:

```
INSERT INTO `entradas`
(`id_entrada`, `producto`, `fecha_entrada`, `cantidad_entrada`)
VALUES
(1, 1, '2018-09-01', 55),
(2, 2, '2018-09-01', 82),
(3, 3, '2018-09-01', 25),
(4, 4, '2018-09-01', 52),
(5, 3, '2018-09-01', 25),
(6, 5, '2018-09-01', 12);

INSERT INTO `salidas`
(`id_salida`, `producto`, `fecha_salida`, `cantidad_salida`)
VALUES
(1, 1, '2018-09-30', 25),
(2, 2, '2018-09-30', 12),
(3, 3, '2018-09-30', 45),
(4, 8, '2018-09-30', 18);
```

Según esos datos, me gustaría obtener lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si me estoy explicando bien, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme con esto...

Comment: Intenta agregando la condicion de la fecha en los `ON` pero usando `LEFT JOIN`. ¿Cuál tipo de dato tienen las fechas?

Comment: Agregué lo que dices... los cálculos no son exactos. Las fechas son de tipo date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que te refieres a combinar las consultas que ya tienes, así:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT producto.codigo_producto,
      SUM(entradas.cantidad_entrada) AS total_entradas,
      entradas.fecha_entrada
      FROM producto JOIN entradas
      ON producto.id_producto = entradas.producto
      WHERE MONTH(entradas.fecha_entrada)
      AND YEAR(fecha_entrada) = '2018'
      GROUP BY producto.codigo_producto
  ) e LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT producto.codigo_producto,
      SUM(salidas.cantidad_salida) AS total_salidas,
      salidas.fecha_salida
      FROM producto JOIN salidas
      ON producto.id_producto = salidas.producto
      WHERE MONTH(salidas.fecha_salida)
      AND YEAR(fecha_salida) = '2018'
      GROUP BY producto.codigo_producto
  ) s USING(codigo_producto)
  ORDER BY codigo_producto ASC;
```

Si combinas las tres tablas con `INNER JOIN` te desaparecerán los artículos que aún no tengan salida y, si además haces un `GROUP BY`, sumarás los que hayan entrado con los que hayan salido. Supongo que es con lo que te has encontrado y por eso has pedido ayuda.

Espero que esto resuelva tu problema. Simplemente es un `JOIN` entre subconsultas en vez de el habitual entre tablas. Fíjate que no ha sido necesario tocar las consultas que ya tenías, simplemente las pones entre paréntesis y les asignas un alias.

El `LEFT JOIN` es para que te aparezcan los productos que tienen entradas, pero aún no tienen salidas. Si necesitas ver todos los productos, aunque no tengan entradas y salidas, utiliza `LEFT JOIN` en vez de `JOIN` justo después del `FROM` de cada subconsulta. E implementa un `FULL JOIN` mendiante una `UNION` de `LEFT JOIN` y `RIGHT JOIN`, tal que así:

```
SELECT codigo_producto,total_entradas,fecha_entrada,
  total_salidas,fecha_salida FROM (
    SELECT producto.codigo_producto,
      SUM(entradas.cantidad_entrada) AS total_entradas,
      entradas.fecha_entrada
      FROM producto LEFT JOIN entradas
      ON producto.id_producto = entradas.producto
      WHERE MONTH(entradas.fecha_entrada)
      AND YEAR(fecha_entrada) = '2018'
      GROUP BY producto.codigo_producto
  ) e LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT producto.codigo_producto,
      SUM(salidas.cantidad_salida) AS total_salidas,
      salidas.fecha_salida
      FROM producto LEFT JOIN salidas
      ON producto.id_producto = salidas.producto
      WHERE MONTH(salidas.fecha_salida)
      AND YEAR(fecha_salida) = '2018'
      GROUP BY producto.codigo_producto
  ) s USING(codigo_producto)
UNION
SELECT codigo_producto,total_entradas,fecha_entrada,
  total_salidas,fecha_salida FROM (
    SELECT producto.codigo_producto,
      SUM(entradas.cantidad_entrada) AS total_entradas,
      entradas.fecha_entrada
      FROM producto LEFT JOIN entradas
      ON producto.id_producto = entradas.producto
      WHERE MONTH(entradas.fecha_entrada)
      AND YEAR(fecha_entrada) = '2018'
      GROUP BY producto.codigo_producto
  ) e RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT producto.codigo_producto,
      SUM(salidas.cantidad_salida) AS total_salidas,
      salidas.fecha_salida
      FROM producto LEFT JOIN salidas
      ON producto.id_producto = salidas.producto
      WHERE MONTH(salidas.fecha_salida)
      AND YEAR(fecha_salida) = '2018'
      GROUP BY producto.codigo_producto
  ) s USING(codigo_producto)
ORDER BY codigo_producto ASC;
```

Aporto la estructura de las tablas para facilitar comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE `producto` (
  `id_producto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codigo_producto` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `entradas` (
  `id_entrada` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `producto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_entrada` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantidad_entrada` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `salidas` (
  `id_salida` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `producto` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_salida` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantidad_salida` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Comment: Efectivamente, lo que estuve intentando no me hacia los cálculos exactos, y como no conozco mucho de sql no sabía que podía intentar, así que recurrí a este foro. La consulta que dejaste me funciona casi perfectamente, es decir, me hace los cálculos exactos, pero me omite algunos resultados :/. Por ejemplo, en mi tabla 'entradas' tengo 6 productos registrados en el mes de septiembre, pero ese mes solo 3 de ellos tuvieron alguna salida... la consulta me omite la entrada de los 3 productos restantes, y necesito mostrar todos los productos que tuvieron alguna entrada o salida

Comment: Para eso tenemos `LEFT JOIN`, te amplío la respuesta...

Comment: Con el LEFT JOIN (incluso en las subconsultas) me aparecen todos los productos que tienen entrada, aunque no tuvieran salida, pero se omiten los que tuvieron salida sin ninguna entrada ese mes. Creo que podría obtener el resultado que necesito utilizando FULL OUTER JOIN, sin embargo, no está disponible en mysql... según lo que estuve investigando, se puede imitar su funcionamiento con LEFT y RIGHT JOIN, pero hasta ahora no había trabajado con subconsultas y no sé cómo podría aplicarlo en este caso :/

Comment: Efectivamente, MySQL no tiene `FULL JOIN` pero sí que puedes hacer una `UNION` de un `LEFT JOIN` y un `RIGHT JOIN`. Te amplío la respuesta con esa `UNION` que equivaldría al `FULL JOIN`

Comment: Intente con la nueva consulta... se repiten algunos productos y los cálculos no son exactos en las entradas y salidas. En las entradas no me aparecen los valores nulos, pero en las salidas si. No se me ocurre que otra cosa intentar :/

Comment: Incorpora una parte del dataset a tu pregunta, con phpMyAdmin->Exportar, e indica el resultado que te gustaría obtener para esos datos de muestra. Vamos a ver qué puede estar pasando... Responde a este comentario cuando lo tengas preparado

Comment: Añadí lo que pediste, bueno, si es que te entendí bien...

Comment: Al hacer el `RIGHT JOIN` se intercambiaba el orden de algunas columnas y por eso aparecían esos duplicados. Ya está corregido, pruébalo y me comentas...

Comment: Muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda, incluso probé la consulta utilizando rangos de fecha y funciona perfectamente :D

Comment: Genial, me alegra que te haya funcionado. Recuerda que también puedes votar la respuesta. Gracias por validarla